# How can I infer a template literal type when concatenating two known string types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have two types: `Action` and `ActionEmitter`. The latter is inferred from the `Action` type and appends the string literal `'Clicked'`.

I am trying to create a function that takes an `Action` as an arg and returns an `ActionEmitter`.

I can make this work with a type guard, but seeing as I already know I have an `Action` I would prefer to be able to infer that a valid `ActionEmitter` is created when I concatenate the string 'Clicked' to my action argument.

Here is my code:

```js
type Action = 'next' | 'previous';

type ActionEmitter = Action extends `${infer u}` ? `${u}Clicked` : never;

function isActionEmitter(s: string | ActionEmitter): s is ActionEmitter {
  switch (s) {
    case 'previousClicked':
    case 'nextClicked':
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

// this works but feels unnecessary 
function createActionEmitterGood(action: Action): ActionEmitter | null {
  const emitter = action + 'Clicked';
  return (isActionEmitter(emitter) && emitter) || null;
}

// fails... is this even possible without casting?
function createActionEmitterBad(action: Action): ActionEmitter | null {
  const clicked = 'Clicked' as const;

  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"nextClicked" | "previousClicked"'
  return action + clicked;
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do in the second function - `createActionEmitterBad` - possible without a type guard or casting to `ActionEmitter`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use string interpolation.

```
return `${action}${clicked}`;
```

Typescript doesn't treat the `+` operator for joining strings with the same type safety. Probably because `+` can do all kinds of bizarre type coercion at runtime. So the template literal form of string interpolation is usually preferred anyway.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=32&pln=25&pc=3#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)